# De-rating/re-rating criteria/theory for frequency in circuit breakers

Tags: frequency, protection, fuses, derating

I'm trying to spec a circuit breaker for a system that will be performing in the 3 kHz range, and am not finding much info on how to calculate a new rating based on frequencies in this range (where everything is rated for 50/60 Hz).

Voltage and current ratings should be 600 VAC and 7A, respectively.

Can anyone point me in the direction of some graphs or pages that give some guidelines on re-rating based on frequency?

Comment: Any DC component?

Comment: Any thermal breaker shouldn't care about frequency, but magnetic breakers have a solenoid whose inductive impedance rises with frequency, and this will likely cause problems. Since manufacturers don't normally characterize this, you'll have to do your own research or work directly with the vendor.

Comment: No DC component.  How critical is the voltage rating?  It seems unreasonably difficult to find something rated for 7A @ 600Vac.

Comment: It should be rated for > 600VAC. Period.

Answer (score 1):

3kHz is only 1.5 decades higher than 50/60Hz, so from an engineering point of view, you may consider that the circuit breaker is likely to perform the same. (But a test is mandatory!)